# Restkit : Download a file on system

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, restkit

I have a really hard time to find how downloading a file with the `restkit` framework ? 
I've got a `webservice` (with base64 auth), which return a file.

When i do a regular "get" call, i did receive the stream (with good mime/types), but i can't find a way of getting the data, to make a `NSData`, and register my file. The response object only have a `bodyString` and `bodyJSON`, but no `bodyDATA`.

Comment: Have you looked at the RestKit documentation and/or examples? What research have you done yourself? If you're not willing to look at API docs or examples, you will will continue to have a hard time doing anything.

Comment: I'm sorry, i've miss the properties part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used RestKit, but accoding to their [API documentation](http://restkit.org/api/master/Classes/RKResponse.html#//api/name/body) the `RKResponse` object has a `body` property that is of type NSData.

Comment: Thanks ! I should search a little more !